# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate() latest index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently trying to update a query using mongoose. However, the updates are always grabbing the older(higher) indexes. I'm trying to get the latest index but "sort" does not seem to work. Below is my code :

```
 const query = { 
        name : req.body.name,
        roomName : req.body.roomName
    }
    const update = { $set: {
        "checkInTime": req.body.checkInTime,
        "totalTime": req.body.totalTime
        }
    };
    const options = {
        sort: {
            "createdAt":-1
        }
    };      

   Ticket.updateOne(query, update, options)
    .then(() =>{
        res.json({
            message : res
        })
    })

    .catch(error =>{
        res.json({
            message : error
        })
    })
```

I have also tried

```
sort:{
  query: -1
}
```

and

```
sort:{
  roomName: -1
}
```

and

```
sort:{
 username: -1
}
```

but nothing seems to work

Comment: Could you provide example data with example output you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [updateOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#mongodb-method-db.collection.updateOne) method does not provide any sorting capability as it assumes your matcing conditions will define one and only one document. You can use [findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) instead:

```
const query = { 
        name : req.body.name,
        roomName : req.body.roomName
}

const update = { $set: {
    "checkInTime": req.body.checkInTime,
    "totalTime": req.body.totalTime
    }
};

const options = {
    sort: {
        "createdAt":-1
    }
};      

Ticket.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
    .then(() =>{
        res.json({
            message : res
        })
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        res.json({
            message : error
        })
    })
```